# How can I integrate formBuilder jquery plugin in my MVC project?

Tags: jquery, npm, model-view-controller, nuget, formbuilder

Requirement to implement this: 
I want to add a feature in my page where end user can create a custom form based on his requirement and can save it as a form-profile.

When adding data he should be able to select the form-profile and based on that input fields will be rendered.

Question: 
All I can see is some npm install and npm run stuff in documentation. I want to include this plugin in my MVC project. How can I do that ? sorry if it sounds silly but I am not a NPM guy so not aware of how that works.

The plugin is : https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a day I found this [codepen formbuilder demo](https://codepen.io/kevinchappell/pen/vLjOL) which uses only basic js files and bootstrap files which demonstrating the basic usage of this plugin. I was able to create a POC with simple html page.

It may be a simple thing to understand for someone working on Node.js day-in and day-out  but I think it will help someone who would face similar issues.

```
[codepen formbuilder demo][1]
```